# Which command works in `jboss` 6.3 to check server status?

Tags: jboss6.x

I am trying to check servers status in domain mode in **`jboss 6.3`** , I cant find the appropriate command, this is the only close I could get to it

```
[domain@zlt09196:9999 /] :read-attribute(name=server-state)
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS014792: Unknown attribute server-state",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
[domain@zlt09196:9999 /]
```

it says server-state as unknown

Answer (score 0):

command you are using is specific to standalone mode, for domain mode use below CLI command:

/host=/server=:read-attribute(name=server-state)